# Groupby and concat strings for dataframe

Tags: pandas

**Question**

Given that `groupedMarket = df.groupby("Market")`

How do I create a new column `Related_Markets` with strings concatenated `"Ticker"+"-"+"Time"+"-"+"Signal"` for other members of `groupedMarket`.

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = [["Bull_Flag","EURUSD","W","FX"],["Bull_Candle","GBPUSD","D","FX"],["Bull_Volume","UK100","H1","Index"],["Bear_Volume","USDCHF","W","FX"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat,columns=['Signal', 'Ticker', 'Time', 'Market'])
```

**DataFrame**

```
    Signal     Ticker      Time        Market
0   Bull_Flag   EURUSD     W            FX
1   Bull_Candle GBPUSD     D            FX
2   Bull_Volume UK100      H1           Index
3   Bear_Volume USDCHF     W            FX
```

**Desired Output**

```
    Signal     Ticker      Time         Market  Related_Markets
0   Bull_Flag   EURUSD     W            FX      GBPUSD-D-Bull_Candle USDCHF-W-Bear_Volume
1   Bull_Candle GBPUSD     D            FX      EURUSD-W-Bull_Flag, USDCHF-W-Bear_Volume
2   Bull_Volume UK100      H1           Index   
3   Bear_Volume USDCHF     W            FX      EURUSD-W-Bull_Flag GBPUSD-D-Bull_Candle
```

If no other group member exists it can either be an empty string `""` or `NaN`.

Comment: *or other members of groupedMarket* - is there a choice here or is it just random excluding the current row?

Comment: It says *random excluding the current row* to me, but there is a reason why I wanted to clarify. Hope you understand. Also IMO , its better to put this in the body of the question..!! (*since comments are temp*)

Comment: All other members of the group excluding current row IIUC as per desired output.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using python sets and `apply`:

```
df['key'] = df[['Ticker', 'Granularity', "Signal"]].apply('-'.join, axis=1)
markets = df.groupby('Market')['key'].apply(set)
df['related-markets'] = df.apply(lambda s: ', '.join(markets[s['Market']].difference([s['key']])), axis=1)
df.drop('key', axis=1)
```

output:

```
        Signal  Ticker Granularity Market                             related-markets
0    Bull_Flag  EURUSD           W     FX  GBPUSD-D-Bull_Candle, USDCHF-W-Bear_Volume
1  Bull_Candle  GBPUSD           D     FX    EURUSD-W-Bull_Flag, USDCHF-W-Bear_Volume
2  Bull_Volume   UK100          H1  Index                                            
3  Bear_Volume  USDCHF           W     FX    EURUSD-W-Bull_Flag, GBPUSD-D-Bull_Candle
```

*NB. there were inconsistencies in your question, such as Time/Granularity, hopefully you can adapt easily*

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    var = dd.apply(lambda ss:','.join(dd.loc[dd.index!=ss.name,'col1'].tolist()),axis=1)
    return var

df1.assign(col1=df1.loc[:,["Ticker","Time","Signal"]]\
    .apply("-".join,axis=1))\
    .assign(col1=lambda dd:dd.groupby('Market')
            .apply(function1).droplevel(0))


----------

       Signal  Ticker Time Market                                       col1
0    Bull_Flag  EURUSD    W     FX  GBPUSD-D-Bull_Candle,USDCHF-W-Bear_Volume
1  Bull_Candle  GBPUSD    D     FX    EURUSD-W-Bull_Flag,USDCHF-W-Bear_Volume
2  Bull_Volume   UK100   H1  Index                                           
3  Bear_Volume  USDCHF    W     FX    EURUSD-W-Bull_Flag,GBPUSD-D-Bull_Candle
```